# User defined sql variables in QueryDsl

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I wish to express the following`mysql` query in `QueryDsl`:

```
SELECT AVG(dd.val) as median_val
 FROM (
  SELECT d.balance as val, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM message_entity d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE d.balance is NOT NULL
  -- put some where clause here
  ORDER BY d.balance
  ) as dd
WHERE dd.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2) );
```

This query is used to get the `MEDIAN` of some column values in the database. The challenge is in expressing the user defined sql variables.

Comment: Are you using JPA?

Comment: @JensSchauder, I want to calculate the median of some data using querydsl since that's what I use for complex queries

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, yes, I am using JPA